# Show a direct link of the window in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, window, textarea

Please help me ! sorry for my wording somewhat confusing !

I need show a direct link of the window in textarea.

Eg:

My link: https://stackoverflow.com/123456.

Use: window.location.href

```
<textarea> ?/?/? window.location.href ?/?/? </textarea>
```

=> How do the results show =>

```
<textarea>https://stackoverflow.com/123456</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>

<title>editable URLs</title>

<textarea id=bad></textarea>

<p contenteditable=true><a id=odd></a></p>

<script>
(function() {
  var bad = document.getElementById('bad'),
      odd = document.getElementById('odd')
  bad.textContent = window.location.href
  odd.href = window.location.href
  odd.textContent = window.location.href
})()
</script>
```

The second one is 'odd' rather than 'good' as you're able to change the text of the URL but A) the link remains the same, and B) you must right-click on it to browse to it.  Maybe you need to take a little bit more control over events to get the editable links that you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with a textarea, you'll need a `contenteditable` `div`.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: It's called a *text*area for a reason, amirite?

Comment: if I replace "textarea" to "input" it will be how?

Comment: @LêTùng glad I could help.